# Dynamically setting remote desktop users group membership via Active Directory Attribute

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, ldap

I've gotten a bit of a strange requirement that I have to fill, and I'm hoping to get working without user intervention down the line.

In our Windows environment we have multiple departments, each with their own AD group. All the workstations in the environment are "assigned" to one of these departments via the "department" attribute in their respective active directory object. The request is that we allow all users from a department to be able to log in to any of the departments computers via RDP.

Currently I have it set up with a single department, and it looks like this:

A "Local Users and Groups" GPO that adds the department group to the "Remote Desktop Users" group, with an LDAP query (item level targeting) to apply it to the correct workstations

Item level targeting example:

[image: Item level targeting example]

GPO Example:

[image: GPO Example]

Testing this on a workstation, and I'm getting

> Error 0x8007055b - Cannot perform this operation on built-in accounts

I'm guessing this is more an issue with how I specified the groups, instead of an issue with my LDAP query~ any ideas where I went wrong? I'm also open to a better way to accomplish this in the first place if anyone has suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this myself. In the Local Users and Groups GPO, if "Remove this item when it is no longer applied" is selected, it changes the action to "Replace", which can not be done on built-in accounts. Changing this to "Update", and selecting "Delete all member groups" accomplished the same thing